# zebra scanner LI4278 sometimes puts enter in the middle of code

Tags: android, barcode, code128

i have problem with getting proper code read in android device. 
I have configured scanner to pretend as bluetooth keyboard and to send "enter" at the end of scan.
When i scan Code-128 code "MIX 001" it sometimes puts enter in wrong place.
Is there any extra setting which i have to apply?

[image]

[image]

Comment: what do You mean by "puts enter in wrong place" on the pickture i can see that its proper formatted, however it looks like it cuts sometimes 0's, meaby clean Your scanner ?

Comment: Scanner is clean, it happens on second device as well.
It sometimes send code as:
MIX 01<enter>0

Comment: I cannot reproduce your barcode via [this site](https://generator.barcodetools.com/). Make sure your barcode includes the check digit and that the scanner is set to validate it.

Comment: Have you tried adding a "Keystroke Delay", it looks like the scanner can support this according to the developer guide and could help the receiving app differentiate between the characters, https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/barcode-scanners/li4278-product-reference-guide-a-en-us.pdf

Comment: Thanks @DarrynCampbell for suggestion. It helped :)